# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ↯ (U+21AF) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: input-encodings

The title says it all, I am trying to add the unicode character ↯ (U+21AF) to my code but I get this error. I have been searching for similar questions but none of the answers worked for me.
I have been trying

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{21af}{\abs}
```

but it did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: hex number needs to be uppercase `{21AF}`

Comment: I'm using MiKTeX and TexMaker

Comment: now I get   `Undefined control sequence. \abs`

Comment: well `\abs` isn't a standard command, what do you want to define it to do?

Comment: to print the unicode character 21AF

Comment: why `\abs`?? any way perhaps use the `stix`  package and `\downzigzagarrow`

Comment: I have read a guide that said to use
`\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{HEX}{\COMMAND}` to define the COMMAND to print the HEX char

Comment: No you read that incorrectly, `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{21AF}{\abs}`  declares the character ↯  in a source file to produce the command `\abs`  which you then need to define to do whatever you want it to do.  so if you just want a tex command to typeset the arrow you do not need this at all, simply use `\downzigzagarrow` from the stix package

Comment: OMG you just probably saved my life and my work. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hex number needs to be uppercase

```
 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{21AF}{\abs}
```

declares the character ↯ in a source file to produce the command `\abs` which you then need to define to do whatever you want it to do. the `stix` package has a command for this so simpler would be

```
 \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{21AF}{\downzigzagarrow}
```

But this is to allow you to type a literal ↯ character, if you just want to typeset the character via a tex command you do not need `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` just use the stix package and `\downzigzagarrow` command will be available.

so if you just want a tex command to typeset the arrow you do not need this at all, simply use \downzigzagarrow from the stix package –

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is use a font with that glyph with xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\begin{document}

↯ ↯ lightning ↯ ↯  and thunder 

\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]

Beside Free fonts, U+21AF slot is also set in a few others fonts, including DejaVu, Symbola, ... WenQuanYi Micro Hei ... and of course Unifont, that unfortunately look like a bitmap font even in the TTF version.